# Turning off checkmarks in UITableView Static Cells

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView with 5 single grouped cells, allowing users to access specific further screens from each option. Users will then return to this screen and I want to be able to place a checkmark against the last selected cell and turn off any previous checkmarks.

I am trying to achieve this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` but can't seem to get it right.

There are a few answers available for dynamic cells but nothing for static, can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to manage this, but one of the easier things to do is to store references to the cells in a collection so that you can easily send messages to all the cells. For example, you could add a property like the following:

<strike>@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(NSArray) *cells;</strike>

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UITableViewCell) NSArray *cells;
```

and connect it to each of the cells in your nib file or storyboard. (If you're not using Interface Builder, drop the `IBOutletCollection`, and populate the array yourself wherever you create the cells.)

Then you can manage selection as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for (UITableViewCell *currCell in self.cells)
    {
        currCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm doing something wrong but the syntax for the property does not work for me as stated. When I type out IBOutletCollection it is asking for a ClassName. Syntax seems OK if I just use IBOutlet. As I'm fairly new to Xcode could you explain how I connect the property to each of the cells (I am using a storyboard)

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax for IBOutletCollection is:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UITableview) NSArray *cells;
```

Comment: it should be `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UITableViewCell) NSArray *cells;`